# Building xarray with dataframe columns as indices

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array, python-xarray

I am working with a large dataset of named bridges, that each have several attributes. Some of the attributes are permanent, but several attributes are updated yearly. The data I received is a .csv file with columns that include 'Name', 'Year', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' for each item. I'm trying to turn this into a 3d xarray. An example of the dataset is below:

[image: Table of attributes for each item]

Just to note, this is a significantly reduced array. I'm working with approximately 40,000 bridges over 30 years with 35 different attributes for each. The attributes are mixed type, with about half being string values and half numerical.

I've tried using a dictionary of dataframes or just taking one attribute at a time. I don't think this is very efficient. I've been interested in using xarray for a while but haven't been able to figure out how to make new dimensions based on existing columns in a dataframe. I've tried the following based on the xarray page for creating new DataArrays:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'Name': ['BridgeA','BridgeB','BridgeC',
              'BridgeA','BridgeB','BridgeC',
              'BridgeA','BridgeB','BridgeC',
              'BridgeA','BridgeB','BridgeC'],
     'Built': [2000, 1995, 2004,
               2000, 1995, 2004,
               2000, 1995, 2004,
               2000, 1995, 2004],
     'Type': ['Steel','Steel','Concrete',
              'Steel','Steel','Concrete',
              'Steel','Steel','Concrete',
              'Steel','Steel','Concrete'],
     'Year': [2015, 2015, 2015, 
              2016, 2016, 2016, 
              2017, 2017, 2017, 
              2018, 2018, 2018],
     'ConditionX': [10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 7, 9, 5, 5, 2, 8, 4],
     'ConditionY': [10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 8, 8, 4, 1, 3, 4, 5],
     'ConditionZ': [10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 10, 5, 6, 3, 6, 6, 6]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

da = xr.DataArray(data = df[['Built','Type','ConditionX','ConditionY','ConditionZ']],
                  dims = ('Name','Year'),
                  coords = {'Name': df['Name'],
                            'Year': df['Year']})
```

I've tried a few different arrangements of the DataArray call, but I'm not sure how to turn it into "three" dimensions, considering one dimension can be the list of attributes. I also tried pd.Dataframe.to_xarray, which worked until I then tried to add a dimension from the Year column. Previously I've used pandas multi-indexing / Panels but this seems to be deprecated and I'd like to avoid its use moving forward. Ideally, I would have a structure similar to this:
[Stacked 3d array example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iJOk.png)

In the end, I want to be able to perform analysis for a single year across multiple bridges (average ConditionX in 2015), as well as condition for particular bridges over the available time range. Does anyone have suggestions on how to get this data into xarray as desired or a different method that may be more applicable?

Comment: You have some really bad data replication in there; you might want to split into a dataframe of bridges and a dataframe of conditions, linked by a bridge ID

Comment: As for the question, what's wrong with `df[df['Year'] == 2015]['ConditionX'].mean()` (10.0) and `df[df['Name'] == 'BridgeA']['ConditionX'].mean()` (7.75)?

Comment: @Nick not sure what you mean by data replication. I oversimplified the analysis I plan to perform, I'm working on condition prediction across multiple affecting factors (some of the bridge attributes affect others). I focused my question on getting the data shaped correctly to maximize efficiency. I could do this with a 3d numpy array but to my knowledge that would be less efficient than an xarray or dataframe. Due to the size of the full dataset (~900 million mixed type data points) efficiency is very important.

Comment: In terms of replication, I was talking about the fact that `BridgeA` was constructed of `Steel` in `2000` is repeated in every row related to `BridgeA`.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to give an indication of the type of computations you want to perform as the best data shape will be dependent on that.

Comment: I'd really like to just get the data in the shape I've indicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***i hope these codes work for you :)***

```
def app_func(d:pd.DataFrame):
    return d.sort_values("Year")

d = df.groupby("Name", dropna=False).apply(app_func)
name = d.Name.unique()
year = d.Year.unique()
attr = d.drop(["Name","Year"], axis=1).columns

da = xr.DataArray(
    data = d.drop(["Name","Year"], axis=1).values.reshape(name.size, year.size, attr.size),
    dims = ["Name", "Year", "Attr"],
    coords = {
        "Name":name,
        "Year":year,
        "Attr":attr
    }
)
da
```